# Not able to monitor file changes via batch script for MySQL Logs

Tags: mysql, file, batch-file

I am not able to monitor file changes for a MySQL slow query log on Windows. The batch script works perfectly fine to monitor other files, but not for this one

```
@echo off
:loop   

for %%i in (C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data\slowlog.txt) do echo %%~ai|find "a">nul || goto :loop
echo file was changed

attrib -a C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data\slowlog.txt
goto :loop
```

This is the batch file to see if the "slowlog.txt" has been changed.

The slowlog is present at

> C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data\slowlog.txt

Comment: `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data\slowlog.txt` is not enclosed in `"`, but contains spaces. For that reason the __FOR__ loop is run three times with `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL` and `Server` and `8.0\Data\slowlog.txt ` assigned to loop variable `i`. That is obviously not what you want as it results in `echo` is run with no text to output and so outputs just the echo state which is passed to `find` instead of the attributes list of the log file. The fix is: `for %%i in ("C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data\slowlog.txt") do`

Comment: The `attrib` command line should be `%SystemRoot%\System32\attrib.exe -a "C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data\slowlog.txt"` with enclosing the file name containing spaces also in double quotes. Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `cmd /?` and read the output help carefully from top of first to bottom of last page where is written that a file name with a space or one of these characters ``&()[]{}^=;!'+,`~`` __must__ be enclosed in double quotes while for other file/folder/argument strings `"` can be omitted although it is better to use always `"` around names.

Comment: PS: I recommend to insert below `:loop` the command line `%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 10 /NOBREAK >nul` to let the batch file pause 10 seconds before running the next file attribute test as otherwise this batch file uses one CPU core at 100% just for checking the file attribute of the log file in an endless loop.